# Put variable into another quote

Tags: php, variables

I have a variable a just want to put another variable (a query data) in but i received an error, i think it's because of the quote.

```
$message .= "Bonjour, <br />
Veuillez trouver ci-joint le bon de livraison de la commande '.$data['CMD_CODE'].' <br />";
```

Thanks.

Comment: You mean you want to insert a string?

Comment: Don't build queries like that. Use prepared statements with PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: @vascowhite How do we know he isn't going to pass $message to a prepared statement?

Comment: @acbabis Because if he was, he wouldn't need to put the variables in, he would use place holders instead.

Comment: @vascowhite I don't understand. If you make a prepared statement with '?' placeholders, then when you bind the parameters, you have to pass your data as parameters to the bindParam function. I don't see how the OP's approach prevents this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mixed `"` and `'` quotes.

```
$message .= "Bonjour, <br />
Veuillez trouver ci-joint le bon de livraison de la commande ".$data['CMD_CODE']." <br />";
```

Comment: I have to write ".$data['CMD_CODE']." ?

Comment: Yes - @SvenWalter is correct. You just had single quotes instead of double quotes by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you were trying to use a single quote to end a string opened with double quotes. Try this:

```
$message .= "Bonjour, <br />"
    "Veuillez trouver ci-joint le bon de livraison de la commande "
    .$data['CMD_CODE']
    ." <br />";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$message .= "Bonjour, <br />
Veuillez trouver ci-joint le bon de livraison de la commande " . $data['CMD_CODE'] . " <br />";
```

You're not using the right quote dear, you need to use " insteaad of ' if you opened with ".